# DocuSign Electronic Signature: Error calling CreateEnvelope: "SIGNATURE_PROVIDER_INVALID_FOR_NONSBS"

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to call the Docusign's C# API CreateEnvelope() method, and my envelope has a RecipientSignatureProvider.
The SignatureProvider is set accordingly to a boolean called isElectronic, when electronic, I assume that there should be no restrictions to send the envelope even if the environment is not certified, but I'm receiving and error still.

Can someone help, please? Am I correct about being able to send electronic signatures like that on non-certified environments?

Code that says that the signature is electronic/digital:

```
if (isElectronic)
{
    signer.RecipientSignatureProviders.Add(new RecipientSignatureProvider(null, null, "UniversalSignaturePen_ImageOnly"));
}
else
{
    signer.RecipientSignatureProviders.Add(new RecipientSignatureProvider(null, null, "UniversalSignaturePen_ICP_SmartCard_TSP"));
}
```

Error message:

```
Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
"errorCode": "SIGNATURE_PROVIDER_INVALID_FOR_NONSBS",
"message": "Signature providers are not valid for this recipient. Standards Based Signatures must be enabled for the sending account. Envelope is not configured for support of recipient signing providers"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Standards Based Signatures is not something that is enabled by default. You'll have to send your account information to either [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/) or your account representative (if this is for production).

If you are an ISV building an app that would be used by more than one customer (Account) you should consider that your code may need to gracefully handle this error.

Comment: Hi @Inbar Gazit , thanks for the help.

But there is one more thing I'd like to understand, about sending documents using e the electronic signature.

When I used to send the envelope using the RecipientSignatureProvider like the code below (without any signature based tag), I was able to send it.

signer.RecipientSignatureProviders.Add(new RecipientSignatureProvider());


Since the "UniversalSignaturePen_ImageOnly" is the default Signature, shouldn't I be able to send it without enabling the SBS on my default dev account?

Comment: Electronic signature should work just fine, and your code that works didn't require SBS because you didn't use SBS features.